# Formula Basics in Salesforce

Tags: formula, formula-field

I am new to Salesforce and need to know if I am reading this Formula correctly. 
Am I correct?

```
IF( CloseDate  =  Account.npo02__FirstCloseDate__c, "New",
IF( Account.npo02__OppAmountLastYear__c > 0, "Renewal",
IF( AND(Account.npo02__OppAmountLastYear__c = 0,        
Account.npo02__TotalOppAmount__c > 0), "Lapsed", "New")))
```

I believe it is saying that:

1. If this is the first close date, then it is classed as "new".
2. If the total opportunity last year is greater than zero it is
   classed "renewal".
3. If the total opportunity last year is nothing AND the
   total opportunity is greater than nothing the it is true that the
   class is "lapsed" but it is false that the class is "new".

Answer (score 1):

Your reading is correct, though I think a better reading would be:

> 1) If the current `CloseDate` is equal to the `FirstCloseDate__c` of
>   the associated `Account` record, then the formula returns *New*
>
> else, 2) If the associated `Account` record's `OppAmountLastYear__c`
>   is greater than 0 then the formula returns *Renewal*
>
> else, 3) If the associated `Account` record's `OppAmountLastYear__c`
>   is equal to 0 **and** the associated  Account record's
>   `TotalOppAmount__c` is greater than 0 then the formula returns
>   *Lapsed*
>
> else, the formula returns *New*

Admittedly, from a purely business perspective, it looks as if the last clause has the symbols reversed. I'd think an Account is lapsed if last year had >0 but nothing this year. But I don't know your business case so I might be mis-reading your intent.

Comment: Thanks for this comment. The meaning of "lapsed" in this case means nothing was give in the last two years, so technically this is correct.

Comment: Excellent. Glad to have helped.

Comment: @raisl Also, you need to understand that in 1) if the CloseDate is equal to the FirstCloseDate__c, then the formula will not check 2) and 3) conditions.

Comment: I think that doesn't pose any danger to the business logic here as the "new" category will simply mean that it is an initial donation within one account. The only danger I see is if the donor where removed from the system and then the re-entered. Technically this wouldn't be accurate.